# Why my PHP project running on Docker open blank page?

Tags: php, docker, nginx

I have this project owned by someone else. So, he gave us the code with the docker configuration ready on docker-compose file. There's a database project that I can open fine, but the project with web server and PHP code I can't.

I'm managed to build the containers of the project successfully but, when I open on Browser, the page is blank.

Here's the instructions he gave us:

First create a network so the webserver can communicate with the database container.

**`docker network create api_core_network` **

Then build the container.

`docker-compose up`

Here's the conf files:

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  webserver-bclinic-v1:
    container_name: webserver-bclinic-v1
    image: nginx:alpine
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/nginx/Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - "app-bclinic-v1"
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www
    networks:
      - api_core_network

  app-bclinic-v1:
    container_name: app-bclinic-v1
    image: php:7.4-fpm-alpine
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/app/Dockerfile
    environment:
      CONTAINER_ROLE: app
    volumes:
      - ./api:/var/www/
    networks:
      - api_core_network

networks:
  api_core_network:
    external: true
```

`Dockerfile` (NGINX)

```
FROM nginx:alpine

COPY docker/nginx/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

# Copy microservice public directory
COPY src /var/www
```

`Dockerfile` (app)

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm-alpine

COPY docker/app/entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod u+x /usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh

# Add Repositories
#RUN rm -f /etc/apk/repositories &&\
#    echo "http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.12/main" >> /etc/apk/repositories && \
#    echo "http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.12/community" >> /etc/apk/repositories

# Add Build Dependencies
RUN apk add --update --no-cache --virtual .build-deps
RUN apk add git \
    openssh \
    libjpeg-turbo-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    libzip-dev \
    zip \
    libxml2-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    libjpeg-turbo-dev \
    freetype-dev \
    oniguruma \
    jpegoptim optipng pngquant gifsicle \
    bzip2-dev \
    freetype \
    libpng \
    libjpeg-turbo \
    unzip \
    py3-setuptools

# Add packages sd
RUN apk add --update --no-cache \
    nano

# Configure & install PHP extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql exif pcntl soap bcmath
#RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg
#RUN docker-php-ext-install gd
RUN apk add --no-cache libpng libpng-dev && docker-php-ext-install gd && apk del libpng-dev && docker-php-ext-install zip

# Add Composer
RUN curl -s https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin/ --filename=composer
ENV COMPOSER_ALLOW_SUPERUSER=1
ENV PATH="./vendor/bin:$PATH"

# Add credentials on build
ARG SSH_PRIVATE_KEY
RUN mkdir /root/.ssh/
RUN echo "${SSH_PRIVATE_KEY}" > /root/.ssh/id_rsa
RUN chmod 600 /root/.ssh/id_rsa

# Ensure Bitbucket domain is accepted
RUN touch /root/.ssh/known_hosts
RUN ssh-keyscan bitbucket.org >> /root/.ssh/known_hosts

# Ajusta o limite de memoria
COPY docker/app/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/php.ini

# Copy microservice code
COPY src /var/www

# Install Composer dependencies
RUN cd /var/www

# Remove credentials
RUN rm -rf /root/.ssh

# Remove build dependencies create user restore@'%' identified by 'restore123'
RUN apk del -f .build-deps

# Update storage permissions
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/app.data



# Setup working directory
WORKDIR /var/www

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh"]
```

I already checked that both containers, database and webserver, is connected to the docker network `api`*`core`*`network` but the page still render blank.

Comment: White empty page means _errors_: enable error outputting, and check server logs. Can be simple syntax error because of incompatible PHP versions

Comment: Hello @Lucas. Are you mapping the folders mentioned in the compose file?
`./src:/var/www`

Comment: I don't think it is because I tested for that. I create a test.php file with '  echo "Test";  ' and tryed to access localhost:80/test.php. It didn't work.

Comment: Hello @NunoOliveira, in the Dockerfile:   COPY src /var/www

Comment: At your compose file you are mounting a local folder `./api:/var/www/`. Are you are of that?